# LibGDX: Inscribing a texture in trapezoid

Tags: libgdx

Lets say I have an image of a spaceship and when it's moving from side to side it should be twisted by some angle. When it's steady and not moving it's parallel to the ground and to the viewports projection matrix. During the movement the shape of the spaceship for the observer turns into a trapezoid. So I am seeking for a way of distorting the image in order to "fit" it into a trapezoid. Here is an image for clarification. 
[image]
This could be easily achieved by using `PerspectiveCamera` and 3D environment. The big trouble is that the game is already written using `OrthographicCamera` and 2D logic. Is there a way of solving this problem without creating a new set of animations and overwriting the whole project in 3D?

Comment: There's some discussion here about how to do trapezoidal sprites, but it will take a lot of work and a lot of math: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290428/implementing-trapezoidal-sprites-in-libgdx/28314276#28314276  You might consider drawing your spaceship sprite to a small FrameBuffer using a PerspectiveCamera and a Decal that rotates. Then draw the FrameBuffer's color texture as your sprite in your game scene. It might require using `glBlendFuncSeparate` to record the correct alpha to your FrameBuffer.